# Windows 10 の PowerShell でSSHキーをコピーする時 ssh-rsa: command not found エラーが発生する

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell

[Windowsでssh-copy-idっぽいことをしたい](https://qiita.com/tabu_ichi2/items/446722c15e6b5678ccad) の記事に従い、Windows 10 の端末からSSHキーをコピーしてみました。

```
cat ~/.ssh/Example-HomePage.pub | ssh non_root_admin@160.XXX.XX.XXX ` 
" ` 
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && ` 
cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ` 
"
```

実行すると「ssh-rsaコマンドが見つかりません」（-bash: line 1: ssh-rsa: command not found）と表示されました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

修正方法と、全部正常に終わった事を確認する方法を教えていただいても宜しいでしょうか。
VPSに導入してあるのは Ubuntu 20.04 です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh-rsa` とは `~/.ssh/Example-HomePage.pub` の先頭部分と思われます。それとは別に

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh &&
cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

が実行されずに画面に表示されている点も気になります。Qiitaの記事通りに正しくコマンドを入力できていないと思われます。
例えば質問文に記載のコマンドですと、PowerShellエスケープ文字`` ` ``の後ろが**改行**ではなく**空白**になっていて行継続できていないようにも見えます。

Comment: 仰る通りでした。ご回答に感謝します。